# How to replace values in a column in a data.frame not equal to randomly selected values with NAs?

Tags: r, replace, na

I randomly selected 30 values from variable `a` in the `df data.frame`.

```
set.seed(123) 
date <- as.Date(seq(as.Date("2003-01-01"), as.Date("2003-05-31"), by = 1), format="%Y-%m-%d") 
a    <- runif(151, 0.005, 2.3) 
df   <- data.frame(date, a) 
#select 30 random samples
rans <-sample(length(df$a), 30)
```

I tried this and it replaced all values in `df$a` that are equal to `rans` with `NAs`.

```
df[,2][rans] <- NA
```

But I want to replace all values in `df$a` that are **NOT EQUAL** to `rans` with `NAs` so I tried the following but it didn't work

```
df[,2][!rans] <- NA            #didn't work           
df[,2][!rans %in% df] <- NA    #replaced all values in df$a with NAs
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be better to use negative index, instead use `setdiff`.  We get the row index of those the sequence of rows that are not found in 'rans' by using the `setdiff`, and then assign the 2nd column values corresponding to those rows as NA.

```
df[setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df)), rans),2] <- NA
```

Or instead of `setdiff`, we use `%in%` to get a logical vector of common elements and then negate (`!`) so that TRUE becomes FALSE and FALSE as TRUE.  Assign the 2nd column values that corresponds to the rows as NA.

```
df[!(seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% rans), 2] <- NA
```

If we use `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), and assign 'a' to 'NA' for those row that doesn't satisfy the condition (as mentioned above).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!(1:.N %in% rans), a:= NA]
```

---

**Why the OP's code didn't work?**

1. **First option**

   ```
   df[,2][!rans] <- NA
   ```

   didn't work because

   ```
   !rans
   #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   #[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```

   gives all `FALSE` values.
   The negation operator (`!`) converts whichever value that is '0' in the `vector/column` to TRUE and all others to FALSE.  As the 'rans' did not have any 0 value, all of them got converted to FALSE.  So, by assigning based on the logical index of all FALSE is not going to replace any corresponding value in the 2nd column to NA.
2. **Second option**

   ```
   df[,2][!rans %in% df] <- NA
   ```

   'df' is a `data.frame` and the values in the columns don't match with the values in 'rans'.  So it will be all FALSE again.

   ```
   rans %in% df
   #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   #[23] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   ```

   By negating the above, all the elements are now TRUE, so it subsets all the values in 2nd column, and by assigning those elements to NA, we get a column with full NA values.

Comment: @akrun... why do you prefer to don't use negative numbers? it sounds like it will take more time to do `setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df)), rans)` than just `-rans`.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto  In this case, it may work with negative index.  But, in general, there could be some problems. For example, consider two vectors that don't have any match and we try to do negative index and the expected output is different.  i.e. `v1 <- 1:3;v2 <- 5:6; v1[-which(v1 %in% v2)]
#integer(0)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your reply, but I don't follow your example. If `v2` is the index, `v1` don't have as many elements, so `v1[-v2]` is the same as `v1`. On the other hand, if `v1` is the index, `v2[-v1]` will give `#integer(0)`. The point here is that both vectors do not represent the same (one is values, the other positions). In general, I prefer to use the value of the vector to filter (so `v1` and `v2` will refer to the same "scale" as in `v1[which(v1 %in% v2)]` or `v1[!which(v1 %in% v2)]` but if you already have the positions, it seems quicker and easier to use them.

Comment: @CarlosAlberto  I am just showing an example where negative index doesn't work.  You can use whatever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df[-rans,2] <- NA
```

the negative values will just discard those elements in the list